# Include blank for first item in select list in options_for_select tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, erb, html-select

I tried `:include_blank => true`, but it didn't work.

```
<select>
    <%= options_for_select Model.all.collect{|mt| [mt.name, mt.id]} %>
</select>
```

If I need to add it to the collection, how would you do that?

Comment: I believe it is the same in rails 2 and 3? You probably want to use the collection_select helper instead of html select tag - more info on include_blank  - http://house9.blogspot.com/2009/04/rails-collectionselect-to-prompt-or.html

Answer (score 98, accepted):

I think you want this format:

```
select("model_name", "model_id", Model.all.collect {|mt| [ mt.name, mt.id ] }, {:include_blank => 'name of your blank prompt'})
```

BTW: was assuming Modle was suppose to be Model. To use using collection_select:

```
collection_select(:model, :model_id, Model.all, :id, :name, :prompt => true)
```

Comment: It works also for a lot of other Rails helpers. I just tried `grouped_collection_select` and it works. Thanks @chris

Comment: FYI, if you're using `select_tag` and you want to include some text for the blank option, you need to use `prompt`, as `include_blank` is only true/false.

Comment: @JoshPinter include_blank can also be set to a string per http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html ":include_blank - set to true or a prompt string if the first option element of the select element is a blank. Useful if there is not a default value required for the select element." This works in Rails 4.2 and possibly earlier.

Comment: @Maltiriel Using `select_tag` on Rails 3 doesn't show the string if you pass it one. I was expecting it to, like the other select methods, but it doesn't. That's why I left a comment to help others. You can see the source here simply delete the `include_blank` value: http://apidock.com/rails/v3.2.13/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/select_tag

Comment: It's not working on edit. It gives me the same value not the blank one!

Answer (score 30):

I believe the `:include_blank` options only exist for `select` fields tied to a model.

Assuming you want to use a plain `<select>` tag instead of a `<%= select(...) %>` tied to a model, you can insert a blank entry at the front of your results:

```
<%= options_for_select Modle.all.collect{|mt| [mt.name, mt.id]}.insert(0, "") %>
```

Comment: This is false. `include_blank:` is an option on the select_tag method, so it will work regardless.

Comment: @tubbo `include_blank:` is great and it is best rails way option. But when only updating collection parameter, then this tricky code is very useful.

Answer (score 29):

Since you have tagged as select-tag you can use the option `include_blank` with `select_tag`.

From the documentation:

```
select_tag "people", options_from_collection_for_select(@people, "id", "name"), :include_blank => true

# => <select id="people" name="people"><option value=""></option><option value="1">David</option></select>
```

Or you can use `options_for_select`:

```
<%= select_tag column.name, options_for_select(Model.all.collect{|mt| [mt.name, mt.id]}), :include_blank => true %>
```

Comment: This is the actual answer to the question. The others involve changing the input structure.

Comment: FYI, with a `select_tag` (notice the `_tag` part) `include_blank` will not display a string that you pass to it. You will need to use `prompt` instead of that.

Comment: This shows a blank option but there is a problem: when editing an existing entity with a specified value for a field, the stored value in the DB is not loaded but what is shown is invariably a blank option.

Answer (score 11):

```
<%= options_for_select Model.all.collect{|x| [x.name,x.id]}.unshift(["",nil]) %>
```

Comment: This idea worked for me, I used it in a select like this: ```f.select :filter_name, options_for_select(Model.order(:name).collect{|x| [x.name,x.id]}.unshift(['-- not set --',0])), {},{ id: 'filterSimpleFilterSelect', class: 'd-none', multiple: true }``` in a dropdown.

Answer (score 1):

```
= select_tag "some_value", options_for_select(Model.all.collect{ |x| [x.name, x.id]}.prepend([t('helpers.some_name'), nil]), :selected => params[:some_value])
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want a slick solution you can use my gem [`rearmed_rails`](https://github.com/westonganger/rearmed_rails) which has a feature in it that safely monkey patches `options_for_select` and `options_for_collection_select`

`rails g rearmed_rails:setup`

Open `config/initializers/rearmed_rails.rb` and change the following values to `true`

```
options_for_select_include_blank: true,
options_from_collection_for_select_include_blank: true
```

Now whenever you need a blank included simply do the following:

```
<%= options_for_select(Model.all.map{|x| [x.name,x.id]}, include_blank: true) %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following monkey patch to add the `include_blank` argument to `options_for_select`

```
module OptionsForSelectIncludeBlankPatch

  def options_for_select(container, selected = nil)
    if selected.is_a?(Hash)
      include_blank = selected[:include_blank] || selected['include_blank']
    end

    options = super

    if include_blank
      include_blank = '' if include_blank == true

      if Rails::VERSION::MAJOR >= 5 && Rails::VERSION::MINOR >= 1
        str = tag_builder.content_tag_string(:option, include_blank, {value: ''})
      else
        str = content_tag_string(:option, include_blank, {value: ''})
      end

      options.prepend(str)
    end

    options
  end

end

ActiveSupport.on_load(:action_view) do
  ActionView::Base.send(:include, RearmedRails::RailsHelpers)
end
```