# How to make the blank option selected by default in Rails using options_from_collection_for_select

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So this is the html produced by the select helper

```
<select id="album_id" class="form-control" size="2" multiple="multiple" name="album_id[]">
<option value="">Nezaradene</option>
<option value="1">Godzone acoustic</option>
<option value="2">Privitajme Pana</option>
<option value="3">Boh je blizko</option>
</select>
```

How do I make the first value selected using options_from_colletion_for_select helper? I know how I can set all the others, but not the blank one.

just fyi, here's the code for the select tag

```
<%= select_tag :album_id, options_from_collection_for_select(Album.all, :id, :name, 0),
                                         multiple: true, include_blank: 'Nezaradene', size: 2, class: 'form-control' %>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you include blank for first item in select list in options\_for\_select tag in Rails 3?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6710965/how-do-you-include-blank-for-first-item-in-select-list-in-options-for-select-tag)

Comment: That question only answers how to include the blank, not how to make it selected.

Comment: if there is an empty value returned, it has to be default value, how about handling this way.

Comment: Thanks, that works. I just wanted to do it without those ifs.

Comment: I have the same issue. It seems crazy to me that there's still no way to do this without using JS. Am I understanding that correctly?