# How to add please select in select_tag rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

my select options from the controller brings as an option could add "please select" Disabled and selected.
Thankyou

```
      <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.label :trade_id, 'Empresa', :class => 'col-lg-2 control-label' %>
      <div class="col-lg-10">
      <%= select_tag "trade_id", options_from_collection_for_select(@trade, "id", "name"),:class => 'form-control' %>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: I believe what you're looking for has already been answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6711058/2280625)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your problem may be solved by adding the "prompt:" parameter in the select_tag, like so:

```
<%= select_tag "trade_id", options_from_collection_for_select(@trade, "id", "name"),:class => 'form-control', prompt: 'please select' %>
```

Comment: Alternative for use f.select?

Comment: Take a look at this discussion: http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/select

Comment: can you join me http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87600/discussions-for-randomnessq ?