# Adding blank values in rails drop down and alert for blank value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I am having a drop down has below in my rails application.

```
= select_tag(:q, options_for_select([["a",1],["b",2]]), class:"select")
```

I need to add a default blank value and it not any value selected and submit button is clicked, user should get a prompt. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Include blank for first item in select list in options\_for\_select tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6710965/include-blank-for-first-item-in-select-list-in-options-for-select-tag)

Comment: @abax, how about adding an alert to the blank value selection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your goal is to include a blank and the selection is required try:

`= select_tag(:q, options_for_select([["a",1],["b",2]]), class:"select", include_blank: true, required: true)`

Comment: How to add some text like, "select one", instead of blank?

Comment: Replace `include_blank: true` with `include_blank: 'select one'`