# Multiple collection inputs binded to one parameter name?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Let's say i have two inputs, where i can select one option (and only one), on each of them. But those inputs binds to the same parameter name:

```
<%= f.input :filter, collection: @traffic_columns, include_hidden: false, disabled: true, required: false, label: "Traffic Dimensions",  input_html: {type: "text" } %>
<%= f.input :filter, collection: @vault_columns, include_hidden: false,label: "Vault", required: false, input_html: {type: "text" } %>
```

I want to select an option in each of the inputs, so i can later have something like params[:filter] = ["option1", "option2"]. Apparently, this is easy without collection, i just add multiple: true inside input_html and i have it, but with the collections is different, since when you add "multiple: true", it means multiple options inside that particular dropdown, but i still want to limit the selection to only 1 option. So, i added this in my controller, to the strong parameters:

```
params.require(:correlation_engine_rule)
      .permit(filter: [])
```

But, it's not working. First, because in my params i only have 1 value, and second, because if i add multiple: true to my collection inputs, it changes the css of the dropdown, and now i can see all the options displayed inside a frame, so it stops working like a dropdown. I don't know what i'm missing so if anyone could help me. Thank you.

Basically, i want it to look like this, like a normal dropdown:

[image]

instead of this, which is the one with the multiple: true

[image]

Also is really weird, because with the multiple true the css of the dropdown is really ugly, as if it was not a dropdown.

Basically i want to have multiples dropdown, with only 1 selectable options, and all those inputs to bind to the same parameter, so i have all the values in order in an array like filter: ["option1", "option2", "option3...]

Thanks.

pd: by the way, i'm using include_hidden: false, but i still see the empty string as first option. This is not relevant to the question but i don't know it is happening.

pd2: seems like include_blank: false works better.

edit: aparently this is not possible. Thanks to Les Nightingill for the answer.

Comment: You could try this answer, uses `include_blank`, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6710965/include-blank-for-first-item-in-select-list-in-options-for-select-tag

Comment: thanks, include_blank works for me better. Still, my main concern is about the other problem, but thanks anyway!!

Comment: You could check out the select2 gem and package. It has css for multiple true that might work with what you need

Comment: You cannot set the same parameter (:filter) in two select boxes and get an array of the two results. You will need to give the param two distinct names (e.g. :traffic_filter, :vault_filter) and combine them into a :filter array on the backend.

Comment: Can i bind the input with the collection to set the value to another parameter in a hidden field? That way i could have a hidden field, named :whatever, so then in my controller i do whatever: [], and then i have all the values as array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly what you wish to achieve, here's how it can be done *without* rails form helpers:

```html
<form action=<%= widgets_url %> method='post'>
  <%= hidden_field_tag :authenticity_token, form_authenticity_token -%>
  <select name='widget[filter][]'>
    <%= options_for_select([['red',1],['green',2],['blue',3]]) %>
  </select>
  <select name='widget[filter][]'>
    <%= options_for_select([['yellow',4],['indigo',5],['violet',6]]) %>
  </select>
  <button type='submit'/>Submit</button>
</form>
```

This form will submit a parameter which has the name `filter` and the value is an array comprised of the selected values from the two select dropdowns. Is this what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Yes! So with this, at the end i could have params[:filter] = ["1", "4"], right? This exactly what i wanted, thanks!

Comment: yes, you'll get params[:filter]=["1","4"]. After telling you it couldn't be done I realized that there is, in fact, a way!